# getting compile-time date and time without macros

Tags: c++, date, time, compiler-construction, macros

using c++

I compile my code on an automated schedule and need to use the time at which the code was compiled in the code itself. Currently I'm just using the `__DATE__`, `__TIME__` macros to get the compile- time date and time. However, this causes the binaries to change even if no changes have been made to the source (macros will inflate at compile time) which is not good (i don't want the setup to think that the binary changed if there have been no changes to the source).

Is it possible to get the compile-time without using any means that would cause the source to change?

Thanks

Comment: Besides saving it in an additional file that is not part of the build, I don't think that's possible...

Comment: In that case you might want to make your build-system to only build if there are any changes. Recompiling just for sake of recompilation when there are no changes to any sources doesn't make much sense.

Comment: (Note: You should edit your post and add backticks around the macros names: "`... the \`__DATE__\`, \`__TIME__\` macros ...`", because currently they appear bold and without the underscores)

Comment: I like both answers ;)

Comment: so you want the date and time of the point of compilation, but you dont want your binaries to change based on that information? so the only way to do that is to ignore that information and make sure it isnt used in anything that gets stored to the binary...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros do what you observe, return a time dependent string.

It depends upon the system (and perhaps the compiler) and notably the build system (like GNU [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) for example).

A possible idea could be to link in a seperate timestamp file, something like (in `make` syntax)

```
timestamp.c:
        date +'const char timestamp[]="%c";' > $@

program: $(OBJECTS) timestamp.c
        $(LINKER.cc) $^ -o $@ $(LIBES)
        rm -f timestamp.c
```

The `timestamp.o`would then be regenerated and your `program`would be relinked at every `make` (so the generated program will indeed change, but most of the code -thru `$(OBJECTS)` make variable- will stay unchanged).

---

Alternatively, you could e.g. log inside some database or textual log file the time of linking, e.g.

```
program: $(OBJECTS)
      $(LINKER.cc) $^ -o $@ $(LIBES)
      date +'$@ built at %c' >> /var/log/build.log
```

(you might use `logger` instead of `date` to get that logged in the syslog)

Then the generated `program` won't change, but you'll have logged somewhere a build timestamp. BTW you could log also some checksum (e.g. `$(shell md5sum program)` in `make` syntax) of your binary program.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't this still cause the resulting binary file to change from build to build? Since the timestamp.c file will also change and the timestamp.0 file will be linked into the binary?

Comment: I need to make it so that the final binaries do not change unless there has been an actual change in source.

Comment: @user1322488 Take his first makefile snippet, but then modify the timestamp.c line by adding a dependency. e.g. `timestamp.c: $(OBJECTS)`  This will make it only regenerate timestamp.c when it's older than any of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the compile-time IN YOUR binaries, then you will have the binary change.

There are several solutions, but I think the main point is that if you rebuild the binaries on a regular basis, it should really only be done if there are actually some changes (either to the build system or to the source code). So make it part of your build system to check if there are changes, and don't build anything if there isn't any changes. A simple way to do this is to check what the "latest version" in the version control system for the source code is. If the latest version is the same as the one used in the previous build, then nothing needs to be built. This will save you generating builds that are identical (apart from build time-stamp), and will resolve the issue of storgin `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` in the binary.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you want.  If it's the last modified
time of the file, getting it will depend on your system and
build system: something like `-D $(shell ls -l
--time-style=long-iso $< | awk '{ print $7, $8 }')` could be used
in the compiler invocation with GNU make under Linux, for
example.  But of course, it means that if an include file was
changed, but not the source, the time and date wouldn't reflect
it.