# Adding text comment to exe file mingw

Tags: c++, mingw

Is there any option/pragma in gcc/mingw/mingw-w64 to add comment to the library/executable file (text string not affecting executing).
Analog of Microsoft and Borland `#pragma comment (#pragma comment (exestr,"...")` and `#pragma comment (user,"...")`
The linker is `ld` of mingw/mingw-w64 project

Comment: It also depends of the linker and operating system

Comment: The linker is mingw32-make, the os is MS Windows.

Comment: That should go into your question. BTW `mingw32-make` is *not* a [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)). It probably is some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ok, the linker is ld of mingw. The mingw and mingw-w64 are windows ports of gcc

Comment: I don't understand why you don't consider generating some C or C++ code for your needs.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Those pragmas generate 1) Text readable on top of exe file listing 2) Are shown with exe file properties (popup menu on exe file in file browser - info fields about author, licence and so on can be placed so)

Comment: `mingw32-make` is GNU Make, they choose that filename to avoid problems on systems that have a different `make` on the path already

Answer (score 2):

You simply could add some global variable, e.g.

```
 const char globname[] = "this comment";
```

You could even make it `volatile`.

Perhaps you want to generate the `globname` using some preprocessor tricks.

You could configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool to compile some `foo.cc` using e.g. `g++ -Wall -g -Dsrcbasename=foo -c foo.cc` (how to do that is a different question) then define some macro in a common header `myheader.hh` included everywhere like

```
#define FILE_ID_HERE(Str,Suf) const char glob_name_##Suf = Str
#define FILE_ID(Str) FILE_ID_HERE(Str,srcbasename)
```

and start your (and every) `foo.cc` with things like

```
#include "myheader.hh"
FILE_ID("this comment");
```

or you might also improve your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) to [generate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17612964/841108) some timestamp file.

And some compilers accepted the [`#ident` directive](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Other-Directives.html#Other-Directives).

And you might write your [compiler plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to understand your own `#pragma` doing similar things. I don't think it is worth the effort.

Remember that some C or C++ code can be *generated*, but how to do that is your concern and depends more of your build procedure than of your compiler. Consider configuring your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool for that purpose. If you use [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [`ninja`](http://ninja-build.org/) you just need to add a few rules for that.

Answer (score 0):

Text information (like version info, copyrights, original file name and so on) can be added to exe/dll file by using versioninfo resources https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058.aspx

This information is readable whithin file explorer

Some IDE add such a file (usually resource.rc) to project automatically.