# How to know about all the files which are compiled together to make an executable?

Tags: gdb, decompiler

We are looking for an procedure through which we can easily list down all the file which are compiled together to make an executable.

Use Case : Suppose, We have large repository and we want to know what all are the files existing in repository which are compiled to make an executable (i.e a.out)

For example :

```
dwarfdump a.out | grep "NS uri"
0x0000064a  [   9, 0] NS uri: "/home/main.c"
0x000006dd  [   2, 0] NS uri: "/home/zzzz.c"
0x000006f1  [   2, 0] NS uri: "/home/yyyy.c"
0x00000705  [   2, 0] NS uri: "/home/xxxx.c"
0x00000719  [   2, 0] NS uri: "/home/wwww.c"
```

but it doesn't listed down the all the header files.
please suggest.

Comment: Why do you ask, and what is the use case? Please **edit your question** to improve it and motive it and give more context....

Comment: Even with the edits, we don't understand if you want only file paths or more. What does *location* mean in your edited question?

Comment: However, your question shows lack of knowledge about DWARF. Please study that format in more detail

Comment: i have modified, hope now you are able to understand.

Comment: Even with the latest edit, your question is not clear enough.... I guess that you want `DW_AT_decl_file` DWARF directives (like mentioned in my answer), but you might need more. Again, you need to study DWARF format (so you need to spend a few days reading about it). And you should explain *why* (and *what for*) you want these files.

Comment: BTW, your file path list is very naive. What about `stdio.h`? What about the *internal* headers it is referring to? What about the files *implementing* `printf` (e.g. [src/stdio/printf.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/printf.c) if you use [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/))? So even with the edits, your question is not clear enough.

Comment: but with the DW_AT_decl_file, doesn't list down the header files.

Comment: I think , i have made my question simple. dont know what you are looking for. I dont require pre defined source and header like /usr/include etc.

Comment: I improved my answer even more. But your question is still a bit naive when you think of all the details (what about *generated* `.c` files, e.g. with `bison` and `#line` directives). I still don't understand what you really want. Perhaps passing `-H` or some `-M` flag to `gcc` might be enough.

Comment: Your use case is too vague. Depending on how your question is understood, it could be trivial (e.g. collect the information given by `gcc -M -H`) or impossible. So I downvoted your question and voted to close it as unclear. And header files often  don't contain any code, so you don't have information about them in DWARF. Without much more motivation and context (why do you need to collect all the files, and what exact files do you want) your question is too broad and unclear.

Comment: Your question is some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), probably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to Extract Source Code From Executable with Debug Symbol Available ?

**You cannot do that**. I guess you are on Linux/x86-64 (and your question is [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific, and debugging format specific). Of course, you should [pass](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `-g` (or [even](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) `-g3`) to all the `gcc` compilation commands for your executable. Without that `-g` or `-g3` option used to compile *every* [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (including perhaps those of shared libraries!) you might not have enough information.

Even with [debug information](http://www.dwarfstd.org/) in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format, the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable don't *contain* source code, but only *references* to source code (e.g. source file path, position as line and column numbers). So the debug information contains stuff like file `src/foo.c`, line 34 column 5 (but don't give anything about the *content* of `src/foo.c` near that position). Of course once `gdb` knows the file path `src/foo.c` it is able to read that source file (if available and up to date w.r.t. executable) so it can list it.

Extracting that debugging meta-data is a different question. Once you have understood DWARF you could use tools like [`objdump`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) or [`readelf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) or [`addr2line`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/addr2line.1.html) or [dwarfdump or libdwarf](http://wiki.dwarfstd.org/index.php?title=Libdwarf_And_Dwarfdump); and you could also script `gdb` (recent versions of GDB may be [extendable](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html) in Python or in Guile) and use it on your ELF executable.

Perhaps you should consider Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace). It uses the DWARF information  to provide nice looking backtraces at runtime.

BTW, `cgdb` is (like `ddd`) only a *front-end* to [`gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) which does all the real work of processing that DWARF information. It is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), you can study its source code.

> i have only `a.out` then i want to list done file names

You might try `dwarfdump -i | grep DW_AT_decl_file` and you could use some [GNU `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html) command instead of `grep`. You need to dive into the [details of DWARF specifications](http://www.dwarfstd.org/Download.php) and you need to understand more about the [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) format.

> It doesn't listed down the all the header files

This is expected. Most header files don't contain any *code*, only *declarations* (e.g. `printf` is not *implemented* in `<stdio.h>` but in some C source file of your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), e.g. in [`tree/src/stdio/printf.c`](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/printf.c) if you use [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/); it is just *declared* in `/usr/include/stdio.h`). DWARF (and other debug information formats) are describing the [binary code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code). And some header files get included only to give access to a few preprocessor macros (which get expanded or skipped at preprocessing time).

Maybe you dream of [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) programming languages, then try Common Lisp (e.g. with [SBCL](http://sbcl.org)).

If your question is how to use `gdb`, then please read the [*Debugging with GDB*](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) manual.

If your question is about [decompilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler), be aware that it is an impossible task in  general (e.g. because of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)). BTW, programs inside most Linux distributions are generally [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so it is quite easy to get the source code (and you could even avoid using proprietary software on Linux).

BTW, you could also do more things at *compilation* time by passing [more flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) to `gcc`. You might [pass](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) `-H` or `-M` (etc...) to `gcc` (in addition of `-g`). You could even consider writing your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to collect the information you want in some database (but that is probably not worth the effort). You could also consider improving your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) (e.g. adding more into your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)) to collect such information. BTW, many large C programs use some [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) techniques by having some `.c` files perhaps containing [`#line` directives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html) *generated* by tools (e.g. [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)) or scripts, then what kind of file path do you want to keep ??

> We are looking for an procedure through which we can easily list down all the files which are compiled together to make an executable.

If you are writing that executable and compiling it from its source code, I would suggest collecting that information at build time. It could be as trivial as passing some `-M` and/or `-H` flag to `gcc`, perhaps into some *generated* `timestamp.c` file (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17612964/841108) for inspiration; but your `timestamp.c` might contain information provided by `gcc -M` etc...). Your timestamp file might contain [`git`](http://git-scm.com/) version control metadata (like generated in [this `Makefile`](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/blob/master/Makefile)). Read also about [reproducible builds](https://reproducible-builds.org/) and about [package managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But how gdb can extract the source code and shows in a separate windows (gdb -tui a.out) same as cgdb.

if you try , you can see the same code is being displayed..

how debugger able to show the real source code.

Comment: I improved my answer to explain how.

Comment: Okzz... i got your point..

According to you, we will only get the file name , function name, line number etc .. right ?

so, how can i extract the source file name and its pathwith the help of gdb ?

Comment: I don't understand what you really mean. Please **edit your question** to improve it (don't comment here to improve your question). I recommend to *motivate* your question and give more context. You should add two paragraphs (with motivation and context) into your question, not as comments...

Comment: @MGem: please improve your own question by editing it. It was downvoted, so it needs improvement.